# OSError: [E053] while running pyresparser package

Tags: python, parsing, resume

I am continuously getting this error while running pyresparser package.
[image: info about error]

[image: info about spacy]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try these steps:

```
pip install spacy==2.3.5

pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1.tar.gz

pip install pyresparser
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use python3 version 3.6.15
I researched for hours and hours, opened up hundreds of tabs.

The only thing that really worked for me I would say is installing all the packages and stuff with python 3.6.15 and using rosetta with terminal.

Make sure u install homebrew86 and pyenv 86 too and everything 86 when you use rosetta terminal.